# How to mock a webservice with JBoss 7

Tags: web-services, wsdl, ejb, cxf, wsdl2java

I ran into a - to me - confusing situation while I tried to mock an existing webservice.

**Abstract**

I am trying to mock an Sharepoint webservice using the generated interfaces from the WSDL of that service. This somehow fails. Naively, I simply set up a webservice EJB implementing the interface that has been generated from the WSDL.

**1. Setup**

We have a JEE Application on JBoss 7. It consumes a SOAP Service provided by Sharepoint DMS. We encapsulated the WSDL API into a standalone DMS API JAR using maven and the CXF plugin. This DMS API is used within a call factory which creates a DocumentSoap from that object - this is a real SOAP client used by the JEE App.

**2. Mock**

For integration test purpose we ship another EJB application together with the product EAR. This other EJB contains services, servlets, data fixtures etc pp. And it shall contain a mock webservice. The webservice should match the specification of the Sharepoint webservice.

**3. What I did**

I set up a new Webservice Bean using the DMS API jar. It looks like this

```
/**
 * Created by me on 23.02.2016.
 */
@WebService(portName = "documentPort"
          , serviceName = "Documents"
          , targetNamespace = "http://FooService.SharePoint.API.Webservices.Documents"
          , name = "Documents"
          , endpointInterface = "de.customer.ws.fooservice.documents.DocumentsSoap")
@Stateless
@Local(DocumentsSoap.class)
public class DmsMockDocumentWebServiceImpl implements DocumentsSoap {
}
```

Then I (successfully) can replace the URL in the call factory with the wdsl location of my bean. So far, so good.

**4. The Problem**

But when I try to access the mock service, I get this error:

```
14:14:51,404 SEVERE [de.customer.ws.onlineanbindung.FooServiceCallFactory] (EJB default - 7) Java Fehlermeldung: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not find service named {http://FooService.SharePoint.API.Webservices.Documents/}Documents in wsdl http://localhost:8080/ProofCenterTestSuite/Documents/Documents?wsdl
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:159) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.4.8-patch-01.jar:2.4.8-patch-01]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:147) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.4.8-patch-01.jar:2.4.8-patch-01]
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.client.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:141)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:57) [jboss-jaxws-api_2.2_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at de.customer.ws.fooservice.documents.Documents.<init>(Documents.java:31) [DMS-API-2.6.6.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    at de.customer.ws.onlineanbindung.FooServiceCallFactory.getDocuments(FooServiceCallFactory.java:121) [PROOFCenter-EJB.jar:]
    at de.customer.ws.onlineanbindung.FooServiceCallFactory.createDocumentsClient(FooServiceCallFactory.java:88) [PROOFCenter-EJB.jar:]
    at de.customer.ws.onlineanbindung.FooServiceCallFactory.getDocumentClient(FooServiceCallFactory.java:79) [PROOFCenter-EJB.jar:]
    at de.customer.ws.onlineanbindung.FooServiceCallFactory.add(FooServiceCallFactory.java:214) [PROOFCenter-EJB.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:36) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:200) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:188) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:76) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:42) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:32) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:181) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at de.customer.ws.onlineanbindung.FooServiceCallFactory$$$view1204.add(Unknown Source) [PROOFCenter-EJB.jar:]
    at de.customer.ws.onlineanbindung.FakturaDocumentStorer.storeDocument(FakturaDocumentStorer.java:47) [PROOFCenter-EJB.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:36) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:226) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:302) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:188) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:76) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:42) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:181) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AsyncFutureInterceptorFactory$1$1.runInvocation(AsyncFutureInterceptorFactory.java:77) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AsyncInvocationTask.run(AsyncInvocationTask.java:73) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
```

**WSDL local vs. remote**

My locally generated WSDL from the same interfaces vastly differs from the one provided by Sharepoint.

Local

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><wsdl:definitions name="Documents" targetNamespace="http://FooService.SharePoint.API.Webservices.Documents" xmlns:ns1="http://FooService.SharePoint.API.Webservices.Documents/" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://FooService.SharePoint.API.Webservices.Documents" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <wsdl:import location="http://localhost:8080/TheProductTestSuite/Documents/Documents?wsdl=DocumentsSoap.wsdl" namespace="http://FooService.SharePoint.API.Webservices.Documents/">
    </wsdl:import>
  <wsdl:binding name="DocumentsSoapBinding" type="ns1:DocumentsSoap">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="AddLinkedFile">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://FooService.SharePoint.API.Webservices.Documents/AddLinkedFile" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="AddLinkedFile">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="AddLinkedFileResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="UploadDocumentBySearchPath">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://FooService.SharePoint.API.Webservices.Documents/UploadDocumentBySearchPath" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="UploadDocumentBySearchPath">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="UploadDocumentBySearchPathResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation> ...
```

The original WSDL loaded by the call factory looks like this:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://FooService.SharePoint.API.Webservices.Documents/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:s1="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" targetNamespace="http://FooService.SharePoint.API.Webservices.Documents/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://FooService.SharePoint.API.Webservices.Documents/">
      <s:import namespace="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" />
      <s:element name="GetDocumentInformationByURL">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="documentURL" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="GetDocumentInformationByURLResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetDocumentInformationByURLResult" type="tns:DocumentInfo" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:complexType name="DocumentInfo">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="VersionLabel" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="IsConvertedFile" type="s:boolean" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="TotalLength" type="s:long" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="URL" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="UniqueID" type="s1:guid" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ListItemID" type="s:int" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ListID" type="s1:guid" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="FilePath" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DependentFiles" type="tns:ArrayOfDependentFile" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Content" type="tns:Content" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="IsLinked" type="s:boolean" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="IsArchived" type="s:boolean" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CheckedOutState" type="tns:SPCheckOutStatus" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
....
```

**Big Question**

Since I generated the DMS API jar from the Sharepoint WSDL, how can it be, that an EJB service implementing that API so vastly differs to the original, that it won't be accepted as a replacement?

Am I missing crucial points? Or is it simply a generation problem - means : A java client API carrying the webservice infos will never result in an EJB webservice matching the prior specification?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of Java EE you're using is different from Sharepoint's WSDL generation implementation. It's normal for SOAP frameworks to differ as there's no single standard for WSDL generation. Only the WSDL language is standardized. Versions differ as well. If you like you can put the WSDL file in the WEB-INF/wsdl directory of your application and then use something like `@WebService(wsdlLocation="yourwsdl.wsdl")` in the EJB.